# Selenium Python: find_element_by_css_selector() using :contains()

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, css-selectors

In Selenium on Python, I'm trying to select an element using

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td:contains('hello world')")
```

Which gives me the error:

```
>>>> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'An invalid or illegal string was specified'
```

I can select elements using many different CSS selectors this way, but using :contains() always seems to throw an error.  NOTE: I get the same error when i try to use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'hello world')]")
```

Please advise.  Thanks!

EDIT: SOLVED!

Problem solved!  Thank you so much for your help!  I had two significant mistakes:
1.) I thought that :contains() was an accepted css3 selector (turns out it is not part of the current spec, which is why i couldn't select that way)
2.) The xpath selector would have been fine except that I was using a parser that assumed xpath would never have any spaces in it, so it split the arguments by spaces.  Therefore, when i passed in the xpath selector

```
//td[contains(text(),'hello world']
```

the parser was truncated it at the space after 'hello' so the xpath selector looked like

```
//td[contains(text(),'hello
```

which clearly would throw an error.  So i need to adjust my parsing to properly read my xpath selector.

Thank you again for all of your fast, helpful answers!

Comment: show us the html content please..

Comment: [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) don't have anything named as `contains` ..

Comment: `cssselect` has support for `:contains()` pseudo-selector but it refers to an early CSS3 draft that was removed (http://pythonhosted.org/cssselect/#supported-selectors). I'm not aware of other projects supporting this pseuso-selector

Comment: @pault. that is jQery one - http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ .  Selenium doesn't support that jQuery one..

Comment: @Babai, the `contains` selector that jQuery has actually comes from Sizzle, not jQuery.

Comment: @JeremyMoritz, Next time, please show real code!

Comment: I would've liked to show the real code, but the abstractions got in the way too much.  It was about 200 lines of code that were involved in getting the string from the initial page to the place where selenium was using it.  It would have looked very cluttered.

Comment: @JeremyMoritz, then you should make it a simple reproducible scenario. How were we to know it was getting truncated? You didn't provide us with the actual XPath you were running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `find_element_by_xpath_selector` with [`find_element_by_xpath`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) (There is no `find_element_by_xpath_selector` method):

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
...
driver = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//td[contains(text(), 'hello')]")
```

---

**COMPLETE EXAMPLE**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://python.org')
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'//a[contains(text(), "Download")]')
link.click()
```

Comment: good catch!  I hadn't made that particular mistake in my actual code though (just in my Stack Overflow question).  I updated the question accordingly.  Still the same error though.

Comment: @JeremyMoritz, Please show your actual code with the url you're dealing with.

Comment: @falsetru what is this `br.find_element_by_xpath(u"//td[contains(text(), 'hello')]")` ? what is `br` ?

Comment: @Babai, It was my mistake, I fixed that. `br` comes from my spike solution. Thank you for comment.

Comment: @falsetru Here's the error I'm getting when i use the xpath method:     selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'The given selector //h3[contains(text(), is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:\nInvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //h3[contains(text(), because of the following error:\n[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"

Comment: @falsetru what is this `driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//td` ? what is `u`?

Comment: Ohkay.. In Ruby that's not needed.. I use Ruby..not Python.. :)

Comment: @Babai, Sure, I did -- even though it was not always ;)

Comment: @JeremyMoritz, I added an complete example. Try it. Let me know if it does lead you to python download page.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing wrong way. You need to create first a driver object as below:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Then navigate to the required url as below:

```
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Then on that `driver` object need to call the required method. There is no **contains** [**`CSS Selectors`**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). You can go ahead by this method [**`find_element_by_xpath`**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) as below :

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'hello')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td:contains('hello world')")

you can use this option too:

> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td*='hello world'")

**Note: * in css_selector works same as contains in XPath**

Reference:
https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors

Comment: Thank you for drawing attention to this selector!  Unfortunately, it doesn't work the way you're claiming here.  If you read your referenced webpage carefully, you'll see that `*=` (like `^=` and `$=`) is used for selecting ATTRIBUTES of elements, NOT the INNER TEXT of those elements.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyMoritz for clearing the confusion.Yes you are right is works for attribute and not text.